# How do I display an ampersand in the appName property of a Teams tab app?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am developing a Teams tab app, and I am having some difficulty with the "appName" in the manifest. The name of the app is "Stop & Think", but when I generate the manifest using the TeamsFX Toolkit, it generates as "Stop `&amp;` Think". I have tried a few different iterations with no success. How do I get it to display as a regular & in the appName property?

Tried:

- & - shows as `&amp;`
- `&amp;` - shows as `&amp;amp;`
- `&#38;` - shows as `&amp;#38;`
- escaping the character (not possible in JSON)

Comment: We are able to repro your issue and raised the bug for the same. We will let you know once we get any updates on it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdpgt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you open a github issue as well, let's track in there: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/8049, thank you!

The templates are rendered with mustache.js, and it's HTML-escaped by default. You can use triple {} to avoid this error. E.g. in manifest:

```
"name": {
      "short": "{{{config.manifest.appName.short}}}",
      "full": "{{{config.manifest.description.short}}}"
},
```